# sprintf type conversion, strange results

Tags: c++

I catch input from keyboard and puts in char

```
char input[64];
```

If i output the result directly on the screen, then all okay...

```
    font.Render((char*)input, input_size , result_coord2, result_space2, FTGL::RENDER_SIDE);
```

But i want to see what would happen if convert char to double, and back.

```
    double result = atof(input);
char temp[64] = {0};
sprintf(temp,"%16.16f",result);
FTPoint result_coord(x/2, y/2, 0);
FTPoint result_space(0, 0, 0);
font.FaceSize(22);
font.Render((char*)temp, input_size , result_coord, result_space, FTGL::RENDER_SIDE);
```

In end i have 2 output on screen, original input and converted.
Sometimes the results are not equal.

Fist frame

[image]

Second frame

[image]

Comment: If this is about `sprintf()` type conversion, what's with the FTGL stuff? That's obviously unrelated to your problem, makes it harder for everyone to reproduce your problem, and [should have been edited out before you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Plus, the eternal trinity: input, observed output, expected output. Without having to figure it out from "commented" screenshots.

Comment: FTGL text to OpenGL out.

Comment: Yes, but **why**, if your problem is with `sprintf()`, not with FTGL? *Isolate* your problem.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Is `temp` different from `input`? What's the difference, what did you expect? Why do you think the `Render` method behaves different with the `temp` argument?

Comment: i add 2 picture, input = keyboard in (char), result = convert (char to double), temp = convert (double to char).

Comment: Since you are apparently unwilling to improve your question beyond inlining the pictures you had previously linked, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Against better judgement regarding the quality of your question, here's what I glimpsed in my crystal ball.

I turned your non-compilable code into a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert( char * input )
{
    double result = atof( input );
    printf( "%16.16f\n", result );
}

int main()
{
    convert( "123.1" );
    convert( "123.12" );
    return 0;
}
```

Observed output:

```
123.0999999999999943
123.1200000000000045
```

This is expected, given the [accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) inherent in floating point representation.

I can only *assume* that the FTGL functions you are using do some internal rounding (off) or truncating of the output, turning the result of converting `"123.1"` to `double` (`123.0999999999999943`) into `123.0`.